# JBoss and CDI Producer

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi

I'm facing a problem with JBoss AS7 / JEE 6 while using a producer for a logger that work's fine with WildFly and JEE 7.

I've created a qualifier:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface BpeLogger {
}
```

A producer class:

```
public class LoggerProducer{
  @Produces
  @BpeLogger
  public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
  }
}
```

And now I'm trying to inject the logger in another CDI Bean with:

```
  @Inject
  @BpeLogger
  private Logger logger;
```

Deploying fails with following exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Logger] with qualifiers [@BpeLogger] at injection point [[field] @Inject @BpeLogger private de.ulc.bpe.web.process.Domino.logger]
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a beans.xml file? It's mandatory in Java EE 6, but optional in Java EE 7.

Comment: Are you running on JBoss AS 7 or on WildFly? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Dumb question: aren't you mixing 2 different `Logger` classes (j.u.l vs. slf4j)?

Comment: It's works with Wildfly, but not with JBoss AS 7.

Comment: @XavierDury It's slf4j...why do you think there is a mix?

Comment: @VWeber, I was asking if you weren't producing a slf4j Logger and trying to inject a java.util.logging.Logger. As your example seemed fine, it could have been that the 2 Loggers are not the same. With so many Java logging frameworks available,  your IDE could have autocompleted the Logger class from the wrong framework.

Comment: @XavierDury I see your point but in fact it's the right (slf4j) logger.

Comment: Is this still a problem? Are you still interested in a solution?

Comment: Still not working in JBoss AS7. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a beans.xml file in the META-INF folder.

You can also try to annotate your LoggerProducer class as a CDI bean directly. E.g. add @Named annotation and possibly a suitable scope. In your case, @Singleton would probably do just fine.

```
@Named
public class LoggerProducer{
  @Produces
  @BpeLogger
  public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
  }
}
```